# Spring security authentication using ldap based on memberOf attribute

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap, role-base-authorization, memberof

I'm using spring authentication against ldap. If the provided user id and password exists in ldap, then I was able to get the user login. I would like to restrict this based on the user's memberOf attribute in the LDAP. If the user has memberOf attribute with a specific CN value (CN=adminaccess or CN=superadminaccess), then authentication/authorization should pass.Else authentication/authorization should fail.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/admin/auth/denied">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/auth/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/dashboard/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMINACCESS','ROLE_SUPERADMINACCESS')"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>   
  <security:ldap-authentication-provider   user-dn-pattern="CN={0},CN=Users" group-search-base="CN=adminaccess,CN=Users" />  
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="ldapContext"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://xxx.ds.yyy.com:389/DC=xxx,DC=ds,DC=yyy,DC=com"/>
    <property name="userDn" value="CN=aaa,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=ds,DC=yyy,DC=com"/>
    <property name="password" value="thepassword"/>
</bean>
```

I always go to the Access Denied page with my above configuration. If I remove the access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMINACCESS','ROLE_SUPERADMINACCESS')" from the security:intercept-url, I'm able to always access with valid user/password, even if the user is not part of adminaccess (which I was hoping would be restricted because my group -search-base had specified CN=adminaccess).
Wondering what the configuration should be:

1. To restrict access to just users who are memberOf CN=adminaccess and/or CN=superadminaccess
2. Specify correct group-search-base. If I specify only CN=Users, I'm getting a timeout as this is going against our corporate ldap. When I looked up users on LDAP browser, I couldnt find a "ou" that couldhelp. With my above configuration group-search-base="CN=adminaccess,CN=Users", I dont get a timeout, but I dont think it is correct either

Comment: I am **not sure** that `group-search-base` is relevant for *account-to-group* membership (i.e. `memberOf` attribute being on the account entry).

Comment: Thank you Paul. Wondering if there is any other way I could restrict my search based of account-to-group membership. I am okay even if the authentication fails (not  just authorization) for users not part of these groups

Comment: It might be possible to use user's credentials to perform LDAP search for his own account. Then you might be able to use LDAP filter so that only accounts with a specific `memberOf` attribute are included. However that might require manual spring-security-ldap configuration (i.e. without the namespace support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way, but I was able to successfully get this working using DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator and updating to the below configuration:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/admin/auth/denied">
<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/auth/login" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/dashboard/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMINACCESS','ROLE_SUPERADMINACCESS')"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="ldapAuthProvider"></security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="ldapContext"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
 <constructor-arg value="ldap://xxx.ds.yyy.com:389/DC=xxx,DC=ds,DC=yyy,DC=com"/>
 <property name="userDn" value="CN=aaa,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=ds,DC=yyy,DC=com"/>
 <property name="password" value="thepassword"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
     class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="ldapContext" />
            <property name="userDnPatterns">
                <list>
                    <value>CN={0},CN=Users</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg ref="ldapContext" />
            <constructor-arg value="CN=Users" />
            <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="CN" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

With this configuration, if the login username/password provided is correct, all the groups that the user is "memberOf" (pattern CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=ds,DC=yyy,DC=com), get loaded as his "roles" (prefixed with ROLE_) and I'm able to manage access to these roles using security:intercept-url

Comment: Do you get LDAP groups as granted authorities from the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() object? My authorities are always empty, and I am trying to achieve to exact same thing as you. Thanks